# for loop adding values with similar sign in a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Create a numeric vector x:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1)
class(x)
```

Assign variable A to the first value of x:

```
A <- x[1]
A
```

Iterate through x and add elements similar in sign to A:

```
for(i in 2:length(x)) {
       if (sign(x[i]) ==  sign(x[i-1]))    
       {A <- A + x[i]}}
```

Somehow, `A` becomes 4 instead of 3! Any help as of why this is happening is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am new to R and I really looked for similar problems and I couldn't find a solution to what may seem to be a very naive problem. I appreciate any help resolving this issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `tail(cumsum(x),1)`?

Comment: Not really. All I want is to calculate how many elements in the vector x with similar sign and stop computations at the first change in sign. Looking at the vector x above, it is obvious that the first three element have the same sign, so I expect the for loop to assign the value 3 to A. What happens is that A becomes 4 instead! I also expect A to be 3 in case the first three elements of x are all negative too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rle` function

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1)
A <- x[1]

out <- rle(x)
with(out, lengths[values == A])
# [1] 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 2
```

First change in sign:

```
A <- with(out, lengths[values == A])[1]
A
# [1] 3
```

If we reverse the signs:

```
x <- -x
# [1] -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1  1

A <- x[1]

out <- rle(x)
A <- with(out, lengths[values == A])[1]
A
# [1] 3
```